# How can I get rid of the animation on the InkWell widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a problem. I have an `InkWell` widget but I don't want it to have that splash screen animation. Is there a way to get rid of this animation?

Comment: Try setting `splashColor: Colors.transparent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the splash animation, do not use `InkWell`. That widget exists only for that.

Instead use `GestureDetector`, which is basically an `InkWell` *without* the animation.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want any feedback you could add `splashColor: Colors.transparent` and `highlightColor: Colors.transparent`

Answer (score 0):

`InkWell` Widget has a [SplashColor](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkResponse/splashColor.html) property

```
class Whatever extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // The InkWell Wraps our custom flat button Widget
    return InkWell(
      // When the user taps the button, show a snackbar
      onTap: () { /*or your custom implementation*/
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Tap'),
        ));
      },
      splashColor: Colors.transparent, /*This is what you need to include*/
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Text('Flat Button'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to write this long answer when you can read the first comment had already provided that solution. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the score that guy had, I thought it would be easy for him to see the actual demonstration of it. :)